# Optional Prompt in Cognos 8.3

Tags: cognos

I'm new to Cognos report studio. I have data organized in query items per business date. The Cognos report shows a data filter by business date. For business date there is a separate table join. This is always one column, one row table with current business date. The Cognos report is scheduled to run everyday after data is populated in the data source. This part works just fine.

However, I want to have ability to run this same report on demand and when I run this report on demand it should prompt me for a date instead of picking it from the database table. I know how to add a prompt but when I add a prompt, my scheduled reports doesn't work! I can't provide any default as it has to be dynamically picking it from the table.

Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Make the date filter (the one derived from the prompt) optional and set a condition on the other filter to be ignored if the prompt has a value.

Answer (score 0):

This is late but could be helpful for other guys. I suggest this:
- In the metadata, make a prompt macro with a default value of current business date
- In the report, make a date prompt using the parameter defined by prompt macro
- In report schedule, leave the date prompt blank to refresh that everyday

This way your schedule runs with refreshed date and also you can pick for a date while manually running a report.